# Logical decoding on a standby node

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

PostgreSQL 9.4 introduced Logical Decoding:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/logicaldecoding.html

It also has Cascade Streaming Replication:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/warm-standby.html#CASCADING-REPLICATION

Logical Decoding seems to be based on Streaming Replication. However a PostgreSQL server will refuse to start a Logical replication slot on a hot standby. It will only allow Logical Decoding on the master node.

What prevents a hot standby node to replicate itself in cascade using Logical Decoding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[A patch was submitted for PostgreSQL 10, but didn't get in](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAMsr+YEVmBJ=dyLw=+kTihmUnGy5_EW4Mig5T0maieg_Zu=XCg@mail.gmail.com).

Work [continues for PostgreSQL 11](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/12/788/).

Clients like pglogical will need modification to support streaming from a standby once the basic functionality is in postgres.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late...

It's essentially just unsupported because nobody had the time to implement it. There's a bunch of complications around reserving the required resources on the primary, and about continuing to correctly work when the standby, or one in a cascade above, is promoted. Nothing impossible, just work.

That kind of question you're probably more likely to get an answer about on the postgresql lists themselves.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was expecting that would be the case and it's good news in a sens.