# Logical decoding on a standby node - any progress?

Tags: postgresql, logical-replication

I read this question:
[Logical decoding on a standby node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30351628/logical-decoding-on-a-standby-node) and checked PostgreSQL documentation and PG mail lists but I did not find any up to date info about possibility to use hot standby replica as master for logical replication to other databases.

Is there any progress in implementation of this feature? Many thanks.

Comment: You should ask that on the [hackers mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-hackers/)

Comment: Thanks, I tried. So we will see....